# checkpoint_completion_target being ignored

Tags: postgresql

I'm testing checkpoint_completion_target in RDS PostgreSQL and see that checkpoint is taking total time of 28.5 seconds. However, I configured the

```
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
checkpoint_timeout = 300
```

According to this, should the checkpoint spread for 300*0.9 which is **270** seconds?
PostgreSQL version 11.10

Log:

```
2021-03-19 16:06:47 UTC::@:[25023]:LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2021-03-19 16:07:16 UTC::@:[25023]:LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 283 buffers (0.2%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=28.500 s, sync=0.006 s, total=28.533 s; sync files=56, longest=0.006 s, average=0.000 s; distance=64990 kB, estimate=68721 kB
```

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/runtime-config-wal.html
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/wal-configuration.html

Answer (score 1):

The checkpointer implements its throttling by napping in 0.1 second chunks.  And there is no provision for taking more than one nap per buffer needing to be written.  So if there is very little work to be done, it will finish early despite the setting of checkpoint_completion_target.

Comment: Thank you @jjanes . Just to confirm, I understand that it depends on the availability of the resources such as CPU, memory and I/O. If there is contention in any of the resources, the checkpointer implements throttling to spread over the process over checkpoint_completion_target and if there is no contention, checkpointer completes the process as early as possible. Am I right?

Comment: Thank you for the answer @jjanes. I would like to know as @Ravi, how it know there is very little to do? I checked the [checkpointer](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/postmaster/checkpointer.c) itself and did not find anything about it. There is `CHECKPOINT_IMMEDIATE` flag but it is not related with completion. Thanks!

Comment: @Laurenz Albe, I am sorry to name you here, but maybe you have any idea about it to say?

Comment: The proper way to tag a person in a question/comment was different. I recently learnt that. So, [Laurenz Albe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6464308/laurenz-albe) might help us.

Comment: @UmutTEKİN  The log message tells you there was very little to do: `wrote 283 buffers`.  That is not very many.  If you want to know before the checkpoint has finished, you could use pg_buffercache to see how many dirty buffers there are at around the time of the start of the checkpoint.

Comment: Thanks @jjanes. Tried to find a certain boundary, but could not find any. It does not check any buffer rate, buffer number or written data. As soon as it can finish, it finishes.